# Ubuntu: Not able to relate free -lh output with top command ouput

Tags: ubuntu, performance, top, ram

I am checking my ram usage using free -lh command and it shows me below results.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           62G        29G        33G       278M       335M        19G
Low:           62G        29G        33G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:       9.1G        53G
Swap:          15G         0B        15G
```

As i can see the used ram is 29GB and available ram is 33GB but when i check the same using `top` command it shows me below output.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23555 glassfi+  20   0 19.896g  5.270g  55092 S   0.0  8.4 121:16.24 java
 2457 hg+       20   0 20.294g  981344  20588 S   0.0  1.5   6:00.18 java
 2615 hg+       20   0 20.294g  950520  20560 S   0.0  1.4   0:22.18 java
 1992 tomcat6   20   0 5783768  518860  20976 S   0.0  0.8   8:05.15 java
.................................................
```

From the above result i can see glassfish is using 19GB RAM and hg+ is using 20GB Ram, it means more than 39 GB RAM is used.

My question is then why free -lh command is showing only 29GB RAM is used

Answer (score 2):

The “VIRT” column shows how much memory the processes have *allocated*, not how much they’re actually using. Processes can allocate more memory than they use; this is particularly true of Java processes which tend to allocate large heaps but don’t necessarily use everything. The “RES” column shows how much they’re using: just over 5GiB for the `glassfish` process, just under 1GiB each for the `hg` processes.

Comment: if "RES' is the actually memory used by process  then sum of "RES"  column values should reach  to 29 GB .  in my case if i add all values of "RES" column then it reaches to only around 9GB. where is remaining 20GB Memory??

Comment: @Sanjay look at the `-/+ buffers/cache` line: the remaining 20GiB is used by the cache and buffers.

Comment: but that line shows only 9.1G not 20Gib

Comment: @Sanjay yes, it shows that the system is only using 9GiB, ignoring the buffers and cache. You can see the buffer and cache sizes in the first line.